# Set Dynamic generated TabItem´s style from App.xaml

Tags: wpf, styles, tabcontrol, tabitem

In my application I have a main window composed by some menus and menu-items and a `TabControl`. In `Window.DataContext`, I reference my `ViewModel` that contains a property of type `ObservableCollection<MyItemModel>` named `Items`.

My `TabControl.ItemsSource` is bound to the `Items` property so the `TabItem`s are declared dynamicaly:

```
<Window>
...
<Window.DataContext>
<local:ViewModel x:Name="model" />
</Window.DataContext>

...

<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />

</Window>
```

Now I want to define a `Style` for my `TabItem`s in App.xaml like this:

```
<App.xaml>
...

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" x:Key="MyTabItem">
...
</Style>

...
<App.xaml>
```

And use this `Style` in my `Window`. But the problem is how if `TabControl` does not have a property for `ItemsStyle` or something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
            ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyTabItem}/>"
```

?

Comment: I have struggled as well to find that property, it should have been named smth. different. TabItemStyle for instance.

Comment: @Vitalij it's there for a good reason. After you get used to the conecpt of ItemsControl you'll definitely appreciate the consistency.